# npm i --save classlist.js fails at postinstall

Tags: node.js, angular, npm-install

I am on windows 10 with latest update. npm version 5.4.1, I tried all possible answers listed everywhere on stackoverflow, github, etc., but nothing seems to be working. Tried following:

- Used command prompt with and w/o admin mode
- Used powershell with and w/o admin mode
- Moved my project workspace to some other drive; other folder;
- Deleted angular project and recreated with ng new (sometimes this fails too with same error at same place, postinstall)
- Updated node, npm, angular, whatever I have with latest version
- Closed everything (but the only powershell used to install)
- Restarted my laptop
- Antivirus on access scan is disabled too.

It always fails with error:

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink
```

or sometimes:

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir
```

Don't know whether it is because of windows 10 or something else but have no luck at all with this npm install thing.

Is there a manual way of performing what npm install performs?

Comment: Have you add node path to environment variables????

Comment: Yes I double checked. Don't know why but now global install seems to be failing too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove node_modules folder in project directory and run npm install again. This went well. Or otherwise do

1. Uninstall node (and npm).
2. And also delete `C:\Users\Skowron\AppData\Roaming\npm` and `C:\Users\Skowron\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache`.
3. Delete node_modules folder in project directory.
4. Reinstall node `8.4.0` (which comes with npm `5.3.0`).

Or as you are using windows.The recommended version for windows is `v6.11.3`.  I am using this node version with npm version `3.10.10`

After that "`npm install --save classlist.js`" Or install it using `npm install classlist --save.` **Problem is with npm version 5** so uninstall it. And install `v4.6.1` . Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, you are my "Masiha", I know now whom I can turn to for nodejs related problems. Turns out to be the npm version 4 & 5. Followed your steps. Didn't update the npm from 3.10.10. Everything works fine on 3.10.10. But I can't stay forever on 3.10.10. Some day it will not be supported. But problem solved for now.

Comment: I am glad it helps. Version 4 is also good it doesn't create any errors. Previously I used version 4 only now I am working with 3.10.10...By the way what is "Masiha"???

Comment: Masiha or Messiah is the chosen one.
I am not migrating to 4 as yet until I am done with the job in hand.

Comment: yes version 3.10.10 is so flexible to use as long as . Till now I didn't get any errors...